# Google Translate / Basic Javascript issue

Tags: javascript, api, google-translate

Given the following

```
    <textarea style="width: 150px; height: 150px" id="sourceText">Hello Justin how are you today?</textarea>
<textarea style="width: 150px; height: 150px" id="translation"></textarea>
<button id="translateMe" value="Translate!" onclick="translateThis();"></button>
<script>
  function translateText(response) {document.getElementById("translation").innerHTML += response.data.translations[0].translatedText;}
  function translateThis(){
      var sourceText = escape(document.getElementById("sourceText").innerHTML);
      var source = 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=MY_KEY_HERE&source=en&target=es&callback=translateText&q=' + sourceText;
      return source;
  }
</script>
```

How can I hook up this button to process the function to put the translated text in to the translation text area?

Comment: Are you sure you should'nt be using ajax to get something back from Google's API, something tells me just referencing the URL won't do much good ?

Comment: Possibly but my Javascript is so rusty I could end up in a pickle could you elaborate?

Comment: As I say in my answer, the Google URL isn't meant to be used via Ajax, but using JSONP (or by a server-side REST API call).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my question this way.

```
<script>          
function callbackDescription(response) {
     document.getElementById("siteDesc" + langCode).innerHTML = response.data.translations[0].translatedText;
              }

              var langCode;

              function translateToLangCode(lang) {
                  langCode = lang;
                  translateDescription();
              }

              function translateDescription() {
                  var faciDescScript = document.createElement('script');
                  faciDescScript.type = 'text/javascript';
                  var sourceText = escape(document.getElementById("siteDescEN").innerHTML);
                  var faciDesc = 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=API_KEY_HEREsource=en&target=' + langCode.toLowerCase() + '&callback=callbackDescription&q=' + sourceText;
                  faciDescScript.src = faciDesc;
                  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(faciDescScript);
              }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've left out a step.  The "source" variable needs to become the `src` attribute of an HTML `script` element.

Take a closer look at their ["getting started"](https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/getting_started#JSONP) doc.

By the way, other folks are pointing you towards AJAX, but that won't actually work.  Because the Google URL is not hosted on your site, you will be prevented from using AJAX by the "same origin" policy.  The Google approach is meant to either use an API call from server-side code (e.g. Java, ASP.NET, Ruby) or be used directly in javascript using a technique called "JSONP" which involves creating a "script" element on-the-fly.

(You should also be aware that, when you use this latter approach, you are exposing your Google Translate API key within the page source, so users can potentially steal it.)

Edited to add: here's the example code from Google's API docs:

```
<div id="sourceText">Hello world</div>
<div id="translation"></div>
<script>
  function translateText(response) {
    document.getElementById("translation").innerHTML += "<br>" + response.data.translations[0].translatedText;
  }
</script>
<script>
  var newScript = document.createElement('script');
  newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
  var sourceText = escape(document.getElementById("sourceText").innerHTML);
  // WARNING: be aware that YOUR-API-KEY inside html is viewable by all your users.
  // Restrict your key to designated domains or use a proxy to hide your key
  // to avoid misuage by other party.
  var source = 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=YOUR-API-KEY&source=en&target=de&callback=translateText&q=' + sourceText;
  newScript.src = source;

  // When we add this script to the head, the request is sent off.
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(newScript);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @JacobM for this the system is a closed one so the extent of security not massively important, but thanks for the heads up. When you say the the source variable needs to become the src of the HTML element how would I manage this correctly within the function?

Comment: I pasted in the example code from Google's API docs.  It's pretty similar to what you have.  But you need to put in the part where you create the script element (`newScript` above) and then assign it's `src` property (`newScript.src = source;`).

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use your favorite AJAX method (Mine being $.ajax in JQuery) to post to that url and then put the response into your text field.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Currently you're building a URL that, if visited, will have the answer you want - an AJAX request will programmatically visit that URL and get data back from it.